# ¿Cómo guardar correctamente estas cadenas de texto?

Tags: c++

Estoy ingresando 5 cadenas de texto, pero solo me permite ingresar 3 y me las guarda de manera escalonada en las 5 posiciones, Porque sucede esto, como lo soluciono..?. No encuentro el error del porque no me ingresa todos los datos.

```
int main(){
    //ingreso los textos
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Texto:\n";
        cin>>stw(50)>>texto;
        mensaje[i]=nombre;
        i++;
        //Muestro los textos
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
            cout<<(j+1)<<mensaje[j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A la "i" no le tienes que sumar al final bro... por que tu for lo hace automáticamente... por eso solo ingresa 3...quitale el i++ del final. y dime si te funciona

Answer (score 3):

Intenta esto:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<"Texto:\n";
    cin>>stw(50)>>texto;
    mensaje[i]=nombre;
}
```

Te ingresa 3 por que a la `i` del `for` le estás sumando 1 cada vez que pasa. En el `for` ya se le está sumando a la `i`, solo quitale el ultimo `i++`;

Comment: Gracias bro, me sirvio perfecto.

Comment: Te agradeceré que puntúes mi respuesta como correcta.